# Solving $35(1-e^{-10k})=20(1-e^{-20k})$

Tags: calculus

I have my equation down to

$35(1-e^{-10k})=20(1-e^{-20k})$ and for the life of me I can't solve, my main issue being I can't take the ln of both sides because I have more than one value on each side, so I would get to

$15=35e^{-10k}-20e^{-20k}$ where taking the ln of each side doesn't really work.  Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Let $x=e^{-10k}$ and you have a quadratic equation.

Comment: I got it!  A simple substitition thanks haha

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce this to a linear equation by recognizing that

$$1-e^{-20 k} = \left (1-e^{-10 k} \right )\left (1+e^{-10 k} \right ) $$

Thus the equation reduces to, when $k \ne 0$,

$$35 = 20 \left (1+e^{-10 k} \right ) $$

so we (nearly) instantly get that

$$k = \frac1{10} \log{\left (\frac{4}{3} \right )} $$